# How to use Apache Camel "direct" in quarkus camel

Tags: apache-camel, quarkus

I have added io.quarkus:quarkus-camel-core to my application, but the direct start does not work within native-image. If I run quarkus in JVM, then it works.

There are projects in Github (https://github.com/apache/camel-quarkus/tree/master/extensions/direct) that somehow indicate that there is an extension planned in future, but it is not officially supported.

How can I make it run with minimal effort, e.g. create own extension project only for direct. If I am adding the existing projects to my Maven pom, I am getting problems with the different Maven coordinates, and at the end the native build tells me that there are duplicates.

What would be a good way to make the "direct" statement from Camel run in quarkus?

By the way, the native build works, i.e. I get an executable, but the injection of the direct statement does not work:

> "org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve
>   endpoint: direct://init due to: No component found with scheme:
>   direct"

Sources:
REST endpoint:

```
@Path("/hello")
public class GreetingResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String hello() {
        ExchangeBuilder exchangeBuilder = new ExchangeBuilder(context);
        Exchange out = template.send("direct:init", exchangeBuilder.build());

        return out.getOut().toString();
    }
```

CamelRouteBuilder:

```
public class CamelSyncRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

    static final String HTTP_ROUTE_ID = "http:camel";
    static long[] times = new long[1];

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("direct:init").routeId(HTTP_ROUTE_ID)
                .setHeader(MyOrderService.class.getName(), MyOrderService::new)
                .setHeader(Filler.class.getName(), Filler::new).process(fill(Filler.class.getName(), "fill"))
                .split(body().tokenize("@"), CamelSyncRouteBuilder.this::aggregate)
                .process(stateless(MyOrderService.class.getName(), "handleOrder")).end().to("log:foo?level=OFF");
    }
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.sap.it.graal</groupId>
  <artifactId>getting-started</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <properties>
    <surefire-plugin.version>2.22.0</surefire-plugin.version>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <quarkus.version>0.19.1</quarkus.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
  </properties>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-bom</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
      <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-camel-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>build</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <systemProperties>
            <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
          </systemProperties>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>native</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>native</name>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <build>
        <plugins>     
          <plugin>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${quarkus.version}</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <goals>
                  <goal>native-image</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <enableHttpUrlHandler>true</enableHttpUrlHandler>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <goals>
                  <goal>integration-test</goal>
                  <goal>verify</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <systemProperties>
                    <native.image.path>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-runner</native.image.path>
                  </systemProperties>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

Answer (score 2):

the `direct` component should work out of the box even without a dedicated extension, as example it is used to create the integration test for the jdbc component (https://github.com/apache/camel-quarkus/tree/master/integration-tests/jdbc).

Can you share more information about your project and set-up ?

Comment: Coding is shared in the post itself

Comment: And the problem is that is works in the usual JVM mode, but after creation of the native image, the error message appears. As you already indicated, it looks like that the native-image generation cannot compute the extension for the direct statement.

Comment: can you share the whole pom ?

Comment: pom.xml is added to the initial post. It was generated by the Maven templates (and after that I was playing around, hopefully I did not change an important setting)

Comment: So I've created a simpler example with a direct endpoint and it apperas to work as expected, see: https://github.com/lburgazzoli/camel-quarkus-examples/tree/master/simple-direct

Comment: Thank you very much for the example. The difference is that the Camel context is created via application properties. For the Camel Context, that is created via that, direct statement is working, but not, if I am creating a new DefaultCamelContext. It is also interesting that the direct-vm statement also does not transfer to the other context.

Comment: Side remark: the native image is slower than the jar with jdk 12. I am just looking into it and throwing away a lot of coding on my side, but it looks like jdk 12 C2-compiler is doing a good job.

Comment: @UlfFildebrandt that’s expected as that’s the goal of quarkus that pre-configure camel context at build time so i.e. the files that make it possible to discover a component are not part of the binary

Comment: My assumption was that the compiler at build-time can analyze and pre-configure the Camel context, but this is obviously not the intention. I have also found a discussion on Stackoverflow, where Claus Ibsen mentioned that it is bad design to have multiple contexts. So, do I get it right that I can only have one Camel context in quarkus?

Comment: @UlfFildebrandt technically you can have more but it will be your responsibility to include what a ‘standard’ contex requires when running as native binary so practically yes, on quarkus the best is to use what the platform provides as it can be optimized

Comment: How do I do " to include what a ‘standard’ contex requires when running as native binary"? Is there an example available?

Comment: @UlfFildebrandt can you share some info about the performance issues you faced ? 

I did a test on my simple code and what I saw is that:
- Java 12: camel context started in 0.017 seconds
- Java 8: camel context started in 0.022 seconds
- Native: camel context started in 0.000 seconds

Comment: @UlfFildebrandt we have a camel-quarkus gitter room https://gitter.im/apache/camel-quarkus, we may chat over there

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem because i didn't learn how exactly Camel works. As it said in logs - you have no Component that provides "direct" URI. So you have to add that Component. There is one in [Camel Quarkus extensions](https://camel.apache.org/camel-quarkus/latest/reference/extensions/direct.html):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-quarkus-direct</artifactId>
</dependency>
```